# How to make folders of application in SD card are not accessible by file manager and other applications?.

Tags: android

I am creating two folders to store images of my application in SD card.but these folder are visible in file manger.i want to prevent access of my folder from outside.i am saving images in that two folders.i am saving like this please help me any one.

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File pictureDir = new File(sdcard, "Image_dir");
if (!pictureDir.exists()) {
    pictureDir.mkdirs();
    }

// saving the image file in the  folder Image_dir
File f = null;
f = new File(pictureDir, file_name);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f.getAbsolutePath());
Bitmap image;
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

Comment: By design [external](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) storage are world readable. If you don't want to do some kind of hack as suggested by others you need to put your files in [internal](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) storage if you want to have them private. You could also put stuff in the DB, but that might be a bit of an overkill for the example.

Answer (score 0):

normally adding a . in front of the name of the folder which will exclude it from media scanners. But with a file manager can still find it.

Comment: Brain is it sure there is no solution for this?

Comment: Yea with out encryption, any file manager will be able to see the folder. But media apps like galleries will not find the folder with a "."in the beginning of the name.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Api Level-8 then I suggest to use [getExternalFilesDir (String type)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29)

instead of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` because there are two benefit using this

- all images and data will be automatically deleted when your application uninstall by user
- images do not visible in the media application (in Gallery).